# url facade in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, facade, laravel-5

In L4 this worked perfectly:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('autor/'.$o->surname)}}">{{$o->surname}}</a>
```

In L5 it produces blank screen

and I need to resort to this:

```
<a href="autor/{{ URL::to($o->surname)}}">{{$o->surname}}</a>
```

How to adjust syntax to make it work?

Where are docs which would help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel 5 uses {{$var}} to escape content , use {!!$var!!} to echo unescaped strings

[laravel 5 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures)